# What is OCaml's equivalent to "mkdir -p"?

Tags: directory, ocaml, mkdir

What is the OCaml equivalent of `mkdir -p`?

That is, create that directory and all missing parent directories, and don't fail if the directory already exists.

For example, Python 3 has `os.makedirs(..., exist_ok=True)`.

Is there such a function in OCaml?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Janestreet core.unix provides `Core.Unix.mkdir_p` which does the `-p` of mkdir.

So there is not a strictly equivalent of python `os.makedirs` that require an extra flag  but this one does the job.

Comment: Note: There is no system call for "mkdir -p" and every language implements that itself, if at all. Ocamls Unix module does not, only add on libraries like Janestreets core do.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. By the way, I was only asking for an equivalent of `mkdir -p`, not for an equivalent of `os.makedirs` - the latter served just as an example.